# Show and hide divs using keyboard keys

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the display of a div on the condition that a certain div's display != none
every time you click a certain key

for example:
if Div1 display = block and the user pressed F7 - 
then change Div1 style to none, and Div2 to block

I figured out how to do that, but after I add more conditions, some of them just get skipped on and I can't figure out why.. So I obviously didn't find the best way to do that

[everytime certain keys are pressed other divs need to be display none and others display block ]

I hope you can help me!

*edit:
Adding my recent attempt:

```
if ((document.getElementById("main60_1").style.display != "none") && (hello == 1 ) && (y == 117)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mains.length; i += 1) {
            mains[i].style.display = 'none'; /* used to hide all the divs with this class*/
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i += 1) {
            columns[i].style.display = 'none'; /* used to hide all the divs with this class*/
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < tks.length; i += 1) {
            tks[i].style.display = 'none'; /* used to hide all the divs with this class*/
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < f9s.length; i += 1) {
            f9s[i].style.display = 'none'; /* used to hide all the divs with this class*/
        }
        document.getElementById("column1_60").style.display = "table";
        document.getElementById("bottom_menu1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("bottom_menu2").style.display = "block";
        console.log('Hi! Im column1_60');   
        y = null; /* I set y back to null each time so there wont be a chain reaction to the same key pressed */
    }
```

hello is a variable for the input I have, and y is a variable for the keycode.

Here I need to show "column1_60" and hide "main60_1", on the condition that "main60_1" is shown, the input value is 1 and the user pressed F7

The rest of the code looks pretty much the same

Comment: _I figured out how to do that, but after I add more conditions, some of them just get skipped on and I can't figure out why._ Can you show us the code?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant code

Comment: Can you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify the question

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you.

```
window.onkeydown = evt => {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    //u
    case 117:
      if (main60_1.classList.contains('none') && hello == 1) {
        const elementsToHide = document.querySelectorAll("mains, div.alertcolumns, tks, f9s");
        Array.from(elementsToHide).forEach((el) => {
          el.classList.add('none');
        });
        bottom_menu1.classList.add('none');
        bottom_menu2.classList.add('block');
        column1_60.classList.add('table');
      }
      break;
    //v
    case 118:
      if (!main60_1.classList.contains('none') && hello == 1) {
        const elementsToHide = document.querySelectorAll("mains, div.alertcolumns, tks, f9s");
        Array.from(elementsToHide).forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.remove('none');
      });
      bottom_menu1.classList.remove('none');
      bottom_menu2.classList.remove('block');
      column1_60.classList.remove('table');
    }
    break;
  }
};
```